# What is the difference between doc_values and fielddata.doc_values mapping settings?

Tags: elasticsearch

Question is about Elasticsearch 1.x

The documentation [says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/doc-values.html#_enabling_doc_values) that setting `"doc_values": true` should suffice to use disk-based fielddata. Like this:

`"string_field": {
  "doc_values": true,
  "type": "string",
  "index": "not_analyzed"
}`

However, there is also a possibility to set `doc_values` as a fielddata format:

`"string_field": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "not_analyzed",
  "fielddata": {
    "format": "doc_values"
  }
}`

So my questions are:

Are these two approaches essentially the same thing?

If not, what is the difference and should they be used together at the same time (I checked, they can, but I don't know if there is any actual benefit from that)?

Answer (score 1):

"fields don't need to be indexed to enable doc values" means you can have `"index": "no"`, for example:

```
"my_field": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "no",
  "fielddata": {
    "format": "doc_values"
  }
}
```

If you want to change format to doc_values, you need to update mapping and reindex your data.

Comment: Thanks, you clarified the point about reindexing. Apparently it is stated explicitly in both blog posts I mentioned, I just didn't read carefully the 2nd one. However, this doesn't answer if there is a difference between `doc_values` and `fielddata.doc_values`. I will update the question to remove confusion about reindexing.